# set GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner for AndroidStudio

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

My instrumentation-tests run with GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner when doing

```
gradle connectedCheck
```

but inside AndroidStudio I have to set this in the configuration every time. In my build.gradle I have in the section android/defaultConfig

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
```

but somehow AndroidStudio 0.5.9 does not pick that up.

code is here: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid

Comment: How are you trying to run your tests?

Comment: right click and then run

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Have you found out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio, **default** can be set using:

```
Run -> Edit Configurations -> Defaults -> Android Tests
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to also enter the test runner class in your tests configuration in Android studio.

If you edit your test configuration in Android Studio, add `com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner` in the "Specific instrumentation runner (optional)" box.

Comment: so you want to avoid having to what my answer says every time you run a test by right clicking?